# CKEDITOR how do i focus blur elements

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

Hello i'm new to CKEDTIOR , and I have some problems . I would like to focus when you click on the ckeditor element , and unfocus when you click outside of it . Can you please help ?

```
 var challengeEd = undefined;
$('#thechallenge').focus(function() {
    challengeEd = CKEDITOR.replace('thechallenge');
});
var solutionEd = undefined;
$('#thesolution').click(function() {
    solutionEd = CKEDITOR.replace('thesolution');
});     
var companyEd = undefined;
$('#thecompany').click(function() {
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace('thecompany');
});
var customeruseEd = undefined;
$('#thecustomeruse').click(function() {
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace('thecustomeruse');
});



$('body').click(function() {
    if (challengeEd != undefined)
        challengeEd.destroy();
    if (solutionEd != undefined)
        solutionEd.destroy();
    if (companyEd != undefined)
        companyEd.destroy();
    if (customeruseEd != undefined)
        customeruseEd.destroy();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good start, but I see there is the problem with `blur` part. It is good to utilize component API and in case of CKEditor there is [`blur` event](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-blur):

> Fired when the editor instance loses the input focus.

So I would go with the code like:

```
[ 'thesolution', 'thechallenge' ].forEach( function( selector ) {

  // Attach focus listener.
  document.querySelector( '#' + selector ).addEventListener( 'focus', function() {

    // Create editor.
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( selector );

    // When instance is ready - focus it.
    editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
      editor.focus();
    } );

    // When editor losses focus - destroy it.
    editor.on( 'blur', function() {
      editor.destroy();
    } );
  } );      
} );
```

for HTML like:

```
<textarea name="thechallenge" id="thechallenge" rows="10" cols="80">  
  <p>Foo Bar Baz</p>
</textarea>

<textarea name="thesolution" id="thesolution" rows="10" cols="80">  
  <p>Foo Bar Baz</p>
</textarea>
```

[Live demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/f1ames/pen/MENyQy)

So for each textfield there are 4 simple steps:

1. Attach `focus` listener (native or you can use jQuery).
2. Initialize editor instance on focus.
3. When editor is ready - focus it (it won't be focused be default after initialization).
4. On blur destroy editor instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution :

```
 for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {
    var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[instance];
    if (editor) {
        // Call showToolBarDiv() when editor get the focus
        editor.on('focus', function (event) {
            showToolBarDiv(event);
        });

        // Call hideToolBarDiv() when editor loses the focus
        editor.on('blur', function (event) {
            hideToolBarDiv(event);
        });

        //Whenever CKEditor get focus. We will show the toolbar span.
        function showToolBarDiv(event) {
            //'event.editor.id' returns the id of the spans used in ckeditr.
            $('#' + event.editor.id + '_top').show();
        }

        function hideToolBarDiv(event) {
            //'event.editor.id' returns the id of the spans used in ckeditr.
            $('#' + event.editor.id + '_top').hide()
        }
    }
}
```

});